# How to find a parent-id of a sharepoint folder?

Tags: api, sharepoint, graph

I want to upload files to a certain existing folder inside a Sharepoint.

PUT /sites/{site-id}/drive/items/{parent-id}:/{filename}:/content

where to find the {parent-id}? I can not seem to find it, how to do this?
i have a folder inside this Site, i want to know the Parent-ID of this folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you donot know the folder id, you can also use the folder name instead of the folder id to upload files:

```
PUT /sites/{site-id}/drive/root:/{folderName}/{filename}:/content
```

To get the folder id:

```
GET /sites/{site-id}/drive/root:/{folderName}
```

[image]